# Как по команде отобрать у определённого пользователя все роли и выдать определённую

Tags: python, discord.py, discord-api

пытался сделать команду отбирающую все роли у заранее записанного(по id) пользователя, а после выдающую ему заранее подготовленную роль. Если у кого-то есть такой код, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.command()
async der your_command(ctx):
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID)
    member = guild.get_member(USER_ID)
    role = guild.get_role(ROLE_ID)
    await member.remove_roles(member.roles)
    await member.add_roles([role])
```

`GUILD_ID` - айди сервера на котором находится пользователь
`USER_ID` - айди пользователя
`ROLE_ID` - айди роли которую надо добавить пользователю